# How do I extract a subString from List of Strings

Tags: javascript

I am trying to extract a substring (in this case the "Firstname") from a list of strings but I don't know the best approach in JavaScript

Here is the plain text list that I am working with:

```
Lead Code: LC123456789
Lead Type ID: 1
Firstname: Joe
Lastname: Bloggs
Addressline1: 123
Addressline2:  NUMBER ROAD
```

I have tried `string.split()` and also tried using regex but that might be over complicating it

Answer (score 0):

If you're given this whole input as a string (including linebreaks), then the best solution is most likely a regular expression. Try this:

```js
const input = `Lead Code: LC123456789
Lead Type ID: 1
Firstname: Joe
Lastname: Bloggs
Addressline1: 123
Addressline2:  NUMBER ROAD`;

const match = input.match(/Firstname: (.*)\n/)[1];
console.log(match);
```

This is the regex:

```
Firstname: (.*)\n
```

`Firstname:`  will match the text preceding what you want, and `(.*)\n` will match any character up to the line break and put it in a match group. The `.match()` method returns an array of the match then all the match groups, so you need to get the second item (or first match group) with `[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const s = `Lead Code: LC123456789
Lead Type ID: 1
Firstname: Joe
Lastname: Bloggs
Addressline1: 123
Addressline2:  NUMBER ROAD`

console.log(s.match(/Firstname: (.*)/m)[1])
```

Comment: I am curious, does `/m` do anything when you don't use `^` or `$`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract any "field" try to split every line first:

```
const arrFields =  `Lead Code: LC123456789
                    Lead Type ID: 1
                    Firstname: Joe
                    Lastname: Bloggs
                    Addressline1: 123
                    Addressline2:  NUMBER ROAD`.split("\n")
```

Then you can create an object with the fields:

```
const fields = {}
arrFields.forEach(el => {
    const [key, val] = el.split(":")
    fields[key] = val
})
```

After that you can access it:

```
console.log(fields["Firstname"]) // Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = `Lead Code: LC123456789
Lead Type ID: 1
Firstname: Joe
Lastname: Bloggs
Addressline1: 123
Addressline2:  NUMBER ROAD`;

console.log(a.match(/^Firstname: (.*)/m)?.at(1));
```

A simple regex is a good approach here. And using the optional chaining (?.) operator will stop it from getting a TypeError when the regex does not match.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK, whats a good way to contact you?